# Graph theory problem involving induction

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph with $n$ vertices, where $n \ge 2$. Prove that $G$ has two vertices $u$ and $v$ with $d(u) = d(v)$.

Hint: if $G$ is nonempty, consider $G — e$ where
$e$ is an edge of $G$, and use induction on the number of edges of $G$.

I am confused on where to start off this problem using the hint my book has given me. I saw a way to do this proof using pigeonhole principle but I have not learned that in my class yet. If someone could show me where I would start induction in this problem or just an idea of where to start. I'd be grateful.

Comment: Does  $G—e$ mean the graph $G $ with $e$ removed?

Comment: I believe that is is what G $-$ e means.

Answer (score 0):

Say that degrees of vertices are all different. Since each degree is at most $n-1$ and at least 0 then since we have $n$ vertices, these degrees must take all possible values beetwen 0 and $n-1$. Specialy there is vertex A with degree 0 and vertex B with degree $n-1$. But then B must be connected with each vertex and also with A. But then A can't have degree 0. A contradiction.

Comment: This implicitly uses pigeonhole (why must the n vertices take all possible values between 0 and n-1?); OP is looking for an inductive proof.

Comment: Yes, this is a way to avoid pigeonhole which is in my opinion an artificial tool to solve the problems.